# Is there a way to get a user's ID from a mention without them being in the guild?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make an unban command by using mentions. If there's a way to get a user's ID by mention without them being in the actual guild I'm executing the command from, that'll be great.

When trying to execute, I get an error telling me that it cannot read property 'id' of undefined. But when I do it while the user is in the guild, it can read it just fine.

My code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "unban",
    aliases: [],
    usage: "{prefix}unban <user>",
    category: "moderation",
    desc: "Unban a banned user.",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        let unbanned1 = message.mentions.users.first().id || args[0];
        let unbanned = await client.users.fetch(unbanned1);

        let ban = await message.guild.fetchBans();

        // MESSAGES

        if (!args[0]) {
            return message.channel.send('❌ - Please specify a user to unban.')
        }

        if (!unbanned) {
            return message.channel.send(`❌ - User not found.`)
        }

        if (!ban.get(unbanned.id)) {
            return message.channel.send("❌ - This user hasn't been banned.")
        }

        // No author permissions
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
            return channel.send("❌ You do not have permissions to ban members.")
        }
        // No bot permissions
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
            return channel.send("❌ I do not have permissions to ban members. Please contact a staff member")
        }

        var user = ban.get(unbanned1);
        message.guild.members.unban(unbanned1);

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("GREEN")
            .setAuthor(user.user.username, user.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setDescription(`${user.user.tag} got unbanned:`)
            .setTitle("User Unbanned Successfully")
            .addField(`By:`, `${message.author.tag}`, true)
            .setThumbnail(user.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: false }))
            .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setTimestamp()


        message.channel.send(embed);
    },
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to match and capture the ID of a user from the user mention pattern, which looks like this: `/<@!?(\d{17,19})>/`

```
<@ - matches these characters literally
!? - optional "!"
(...) - captures everything inside for later use
\d - any digit
{17-19} - 17 to 19 of the preceding character (\d)
> - matches this character literally
```

You can execute the match with this code:

```js
const match = args[0].match(/<@!?(\d{17,19})>/);
```

If nothing is found, this will return `null`. Otherwise, it will return an array with this structure:

```js
[
  '<@!id_here>',
  'id_here',
  index: 0,
  input: '<@!id_here>',
  groups: undefined
]
```

So, to get the ID, simply grab the second element (at index 1)

```js
// I'm using the optional chaining operator (?.) in the below
// example, which requires node 14.0.0
// if you do not have this version, just separate the `match()` result
// into a separate variable
// and validate it exists before accessing match[1]
let unbanned1 = args[0].match(/<@!?(\d{17,19})>/)?.[1] || args[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get user's id from mention if they are not in the guild. Since they are not `GuildMember`s and you can't mention them. (Yes there is a way to mention user that is not in a guild by using their id, but `discord.js` does not recognize that as a valid mention I think.)

Nice workaround would be to use the `BanInfo` since it contaions a `User` object. Get the `id` from there. If you want to unban users by their usernames, you can compare the `username` property of the `User` in `BanInfo` with the username that the person who sent the unban command specified.

But be aware that usernames are not unique, so it would probably be nice to also use the `discriminator` property of `User`.